Unable to Boot GRUB After Switching to a New PC
After upgrading my PC hardware, I can no longer boot into the GRUB boot manager. I’ve enabled CSM and configured the BIOS to use Legacy Boot, just like my previous setup.
I’ve also successfully updated GRUB using a live USB running Ubuntu. However, when I try to boot directly from the drive containing GRUB, I get the following error:
"Reboot and Select proper Boot Device"
Hardware Changes
Motherboard: ASUS B450 → MSI X570
CPU: Ryzen 5 3500X → Ryzen 7 5800X3D
GPU: GTX 1650 → RX 6800

Storage and Software Setup
NVMe Drive 1: Contains GRUB and Kali Linux (using an encrypted LVM).
NVMe Drive 2: Contains Windows 10

.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken
Enabled CSM and set the BIOS to Legacy Boot mode.
Booted into a live Ubuntu USB and successfully updated GRUB.
Despite these efforts, the system fails to boot into GRUB and displays the error:
"Reboot and Select proper Boot Device"
Question
Could the new motherboard/BIOS require additional configuration for Legacy Boot to work with GRUB? Is switching to UEFI a better option, and if so, how can I safely transition my current setup?
Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Was Windows 10 installed in UEFI or Legacy mode?

@Ramhound Windows should have been installed in Legacy mode. I never remember messing with CSM on my old rig

The old motherboard was UEFI already. Why would you have installed in Legacy mode before? Try undoing what you changed so far...

@ChanganAuto I have reset my motherboard to optimised defaults and unfortunately it does not give me the option to boot to grub. It should be noted a new mass storage device shows up but when   I select that it closes bios ui and reopens on boot select making a loop

You ask if you should switch to UEFI, but if Windows was installed in Legacy Mode, that is impossible to do since MBR does not support UEFI mode. You can no longer boot into GRUB but can you boot into Windows?

On my old motherboard I was booting using legacy and uefi. Sorry for the confusion this is a very nee topic to me

While tinkering with grub more in a live envioment and when running grub-install the output indicates that grub was unable to set EFI variables on my system.
I ammended this by making a efi entry using efibootmgr
Here are the steps I took
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt #mount EFI partition 

Install Grub on device
efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/nvme0n1 --part 1 --loader /EFI/GRUB/grubx64.efi --label "GRUB"


Verify using and checking a boot entry called GRUB is now there.
efibootmgr


